# How to solve it?

Tags: python

Write a program that randomly fills in 0s and 1s into a 4 * 4 matrix, prints the matrix, and finds the rows and columns with the most 1s. Here is a sample run of the program:
0011
0011
1101
1010
The largest row index: 2
The largest column index: 2, 3
What should I edit to make sure that each element in the matrix is random?

Thats what i have for right now:

```
for i in range(4):
    n=0
    for j in range(4):
        n = random.randrange(0,2)   
        arr[i][j]=n

for i in range(4):
    for j in range(4):
        print(arr[i][j],end=" ")  
    print("\n")  
  
row=[]
col=[]
array=[]
array1=[]
sum1=0
for i in range(4):
    sum1 = arr[i][0] + arr[i][1]+arr[i][2]+arr[i][3]
    array.append(sum1)
    sum1=0
    sum1 = arr[0][i] + arr[1][i]+arr[2][i]+arr[3][i]
    array1.append(sum1)
  
m=array[0]
m1=array1[0]
for i in range(1,4):
    if array[i]>m:
        m=array[i]
    if array1[i]>m1:
        m1=array1[i]
for i in range(4):
    if m==array[i]:
        row.append(i)
    if m1==array1[i]:
        col.append(i)
      
print("The largest row index: ",*row)
print("The largest column index: ",*col)
```

Comment: And what problems have you encountered?  Does this work?

Comment: `random.randint(0,2)` produces an integer from the set (0,1,2).  You want `random.randint(0,1)`.  This is an exception to the usual Python rule that excludes the endpoint.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't really care about time complexity here is a small version.

```
from random import randrange

mat = [[randrange(2) for _ in range(4)]for _ in range(4)] # create a matrix


row = max(enumerate(mat), key=lambda x:sum(x[1]))[0] # find the max sum per row, get the zeroth element for index
transpose = list(zip(*mat)) # transpose the matrix
col = max(enumerate(transpose), key=lambda x:sum(x[1]))[0] # now the same logic applies to column sum
print(row, col)
```

This returns only one max row or max col.

Comment: I think an introductory Python teacher is going to be a bit suspicious at seeing this response...